# Add telephone number to ical

Tags: icalendar

Is it possible to add a telephone number to an ical file? I currently have this set as the "ORGANIZER":

```
ORGANIZER;CN="{ORGANIZER_NAME}":mailto:{ORGANIZER_EMAIL}
```

I would like to add a phone number to be able to call the ORGANIZER from e.g. Apple calendar.

Answer (score 0):

According to the RFC5545 specification, the organizer is of value type CAL-ADDRESS.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.3

If one follows through on CAL-ADDRESS https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.3, it is defined as

> The value is a URI as defined by [RFC3986] or any other IANA-registered form for a URI.

If one then clicks through on the RFC3986 specification link, to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1.2 and in particular the examples being easier to understand, one sees a tel example

```
tel:+1-816-555-1212
```

so just like the mail-to, one should be able to use .
Of course one has to check whether the receiving applications will cope with it.  They don't support the specs 100%.

Comment: Simply adding tel: results in the telephone button lighting up (on iPhone) but it uses the mail address as value and the number seems to be discarded.

Comment: The way I read the spec, it indicates a single CAL-ADDRESS, so perhaps that is the proble.    Did you try with just tel:?  Or alternatively if want both email and tel, try using either CONTACT or RSVP for one of the cal-address. 

https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.2 suggests ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:jsmith@example.com 

and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.2 suggests a less structured format, but perhaps receiving applications will parse ? 
CONTACT:Jim Dolittle\, ABC Industries\, +1-919-555-1234